# How do I know the correct format for my input data into my keras RNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to build an Elman simple RNN as described [here](https://web.stanford.edu/group/pdplab/pdphandbook/handbookch8.html).

I've built my model using Keras as follows:

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.SimpleRNN(7,activation =None,use_bias=True,input_shape=
                             [x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1]]))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(7,activation = tf.nn.sigmoid))

model.summary()
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
simple_rnn_2 (SimpleRNN)     (None, 7)                 105       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 7)                 56        
=================================================================
Total params: 161
Trainable params: 161
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

My training data is currently of shape (15000, 7, 7). That is, 15000 instances of length 7 one hot encodings, coding for one of seven letters. E.g `[0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0]` and so forth.

The data's labels are the same format, since each letter predicts the next letter in the sequence, i.e `[0,1,0,0,0,0,0]` has the label `[0,0,1,0,0,0,0]`.

So, training data `(x_train)` and training labels `(y_train)` are both shaped `(15000,7,7)`.

My validation data x_val and y_val are shaped `(10000,7,7)`. I.e the same shape just with fewer instances.

So when I run my model:

```
history = model.fit(x_train,
         y_train,
         epochs = 40,
         batch_size=512,
         validation_data = (x_val,y_val))
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected simple_rnn_7_input to have shape (15000, 7) but got array with shape (7, 7)
```

Clearly my input data is formatted incorrectly for input into the Keras RNN, but I can't think how to feed it the correct input.

Could anyone advise me as to the solution?

Comment: an RNN takes 3-D input. The first is the batch size (number of examples = 165k), and second is the time-related axis (which looks like you are missing) and the third is the vector at each given time (=7). In case of sentences, time would be equivalent to number of words or number of letters in the sentence

Comment: thanks @GergesDib. Please see my edited post. I altered it so that input was 3D and get a similar, but not identical error.

Comment: make `input_shape = x_train.shape[1:]`

Comment: now i get `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_8 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (15000, 7, 7)` - - suddenly it expects 2d input? I tried adding a flatten layer which did nothing too

Comment: weird. one thing to try is restart your python session. looks like you are working in a notebook or interactive session?

Comment: that didnt help unfortunatley..but yes running on notebook!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. SimpleRNN layer expects the inputs of dimensions `(seq_length, input_dim)` that is (7,7) in your case.
2. Also if you want output at each time-step, you need to use `return_sequence=True`, by default which is `false`. This way you can compare the output at time-step.

So the model architecture will be something like this:

```
model.add(keras.layers.SimpleRNN(7, activation='tanh', 
                       return_sequences=True, 
                        input_shape=[7,7]))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(7))
model.summary()

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
simple_rnn_12 (SimpleRNN)    (None, 7, 7)              105       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 7, 7)              56        
=================================================================
Total params: 161
Trainable params: 161
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Now at training time, it expects data `input and output` of dims `(num_samples, seq_length, input_dims)` i.e. `(15000, 7, 7)` for both.

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')# define any loss, you want
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=2)
```

Comment: HereItIs, if this answer solve your problem, please upvote and accept it.